# Wait For Each AsyncTask to finish before executing the next AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have 4 AsyncTask classes in my Fragment. I want to execute all four of them, but one at a time. I have tried things like task.execute().get() and task.execute().getStatus(). These don't seem to work well - I get an error that I can't run another task when a task is running. These are the 4 AsyncTasks I am trying to run:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setTitle("Finalizing Your Run");
    dialog.setMessage("We hope you had fun running! Please wait while we send your running data to our system. This may take a few seconds depending on your internet connection");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
    //All the async tasks to be executed
    AddRouteCheckpoints checkpointTask = new AddRouteCheckpoints(getActivity(), dialog);
    GetRouteIdTask routeIdTask = new GetRouteIdTask(getActivity(), dialog);
    AddRouteTask addRouteTask = new AddRouteTask(getActivity(), dialog);
    AddRunTask personalRunTask = new AddRunTask(getActivity(), dialog);
```

Is there a way of ensuring each AsyncTask completes its task completely before moving on to the next AsyncTask?

Comment: You can provide callback interfaces to each and then call the next one from within them

Comment: Where is your `execute`? And besides that `get` will wait until a result is available. Your implementation is probably flawed.

Comment: "Is there a way of ensuring each AsyncTask completes its task completely before moving on to the next AsyncTask" Sounds to me if it were better to do everything that is now spread among 4 Tasks in one single Task?

Comment: Look at the approach I used when answering this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954261/how-to-pass-data-from-broadcastreceiver-to-activity-without-in-oncreate/38954540#38954540

Answer (score 2):

Why not execute those AsyncTasks in an SingleThreadExecutor?

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

And then execute your task on your executor:

```
task.executeOnExecutor(executor);
```

This way only one thread will be used to run your AsyncTasks and the other ones will be queued.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check progress of each async task on progressupdate if it is 100% then in onpost give call to next one
2. you can also sendbroadcast on successful executoin of one.
3. You can also create interfaces to each and then call them and call the next one.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some same situation the other day. I had solved it in this way: Pass the reference of your activity to the constructor of async class and execute the do in background function. Now in post execute function call a public method of ur activity from async class to execute the task again... or try this:

```
    if (asynclass.getStatus() == android.os.AsyncTask.Status.PENDING) {
        asynclass.execute();
    } else if (RF.getStatus() == android.os.AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
        asynclass = new asyncclass();
        asynclass.execute();
    } else {
        Toast.maketoast(this, "Plz wait", 1).show();
    }
```

Or you can do it as below

You can do it with myAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor (SERIAL_EXECUTOR)

```
AsyncTask a = new AsyncTask();
AsyncTask b = new AsyncTask();
AsyncTask c = new AsyncTask();

a.executeOnExecutor (SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
b.executeOnExecutor (SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
c.executeOnExecutor (SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
```

Cheers