# Android studio how to receive textmessage in edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext, broadcastreceiver

Iam building an application that should receive textMessage from specified number.
Is there anyway to recieve textmessage in an Edittext. here is the class for receiving sms:

```
class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION ="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String SMS_SENDER="123456789";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null &&
                ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {
            Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduArray[i]);
            }
            // SMS Sender, example: 123456789
            String sms_from = messages[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

            //Lets check if SMS sender is 123456789
            if (sms_from.equalsIgnoreCase(SMS_SENDER)) {
                StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();

                // If SMS has several parts, lets combine it :)
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    bodyText.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
                }
                //SMS Body
                String body = bodyText.toString();
                // Lets get SMS Code
                String code  = body.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really need help with this

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand BroadcastReceiver by [Android Developer Document](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts).

In your case, you need to get the result from BroadcastReceiver to Activity, and then you can set the value to EditText.
You can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38954621/17364139).

Comment: Only need to set the value of recieved sms  to EditText.

Comment: I am still having difficulty bypassing this issue and would like to have some help. I am newbe and could not figure it out. in advance thank you.